# Title not showing up - Fancy Box Plugin for e107

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fancybox

I've looked around searching for the solution to this. I've seen people have problems with wordpress but I use e107. Trying to solve why my title shows up perfect on one of my websites. I've copy and pasted the two section of code on the website pages that are associated with fancy box.
The first one works perfect. The second one.. the slide show of pictures pops up like it should be the title for each image does not show up for each photo like it does for the first website.  Occasionally the very first title will show for the first picture and then nothing for the rest.

**Perfectly functioning fancybox code:**
http://jemfarmapps.com/jem/page.php?61

```
<!-- *META* -->
<!-- fancybox meta -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/youtube.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="e107_plugins/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$var = jQuery.noConflict();
$var(document).ready(function($) { 
    if ($('*').is('a[id="fancybox"]')) { 
        $var('a[id="fancybox"]').fancybox({
                'zoomSpeedIn':  500, 
                'zoomSpeedOut': 400, 
                'overlayShow':      false,
                'overlayOpacity': 0.0,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
                 'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over'
        }); 
    } 

$var("a.group").attr('rel','gallery').fancybox({
'zoomSpeedIn':      500, 
                'zoomSpeedOut': 400, 
                'overlayShow':      false,
                'overlayOpacity': 0.0,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
                 'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over'
        }); 

            $var("a#inline").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': true,
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.6,
                                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
            });
});
</script>


<a id="fancybox" href="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles13.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="group" rel="group1"  title="LCAC July 2016"><img src="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles13t.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles14.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="group" rel="group1"  title="CVMHA May  2016"><img src="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles14t.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles12.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="group" rel="group1"  title="September 2016"><img src="http://jsorrell84.powweb.com/jem/images/horses/styles/styles12t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

**I used the same code for the next website and installs the same fancy box plugin:**  But titles do not show on the website.
http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/page.php?5

```
<!-- *META* -->
<!-- fancybox meta -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/youtube.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="e107_plugins/fancybox/scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="e107_plugins/fancybox/css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$var = jQuery.noConflict();
$var(document).ready(function($) { 
    if ($('*').is('a[id="fancybox"]')) { 
        $var('a[id="fancybox"]').fancybox({
                'zoomSpeedIn':  500, 
                'zoomSpeedOut': 400, 
                'overlayShow':      false,
                'overlayOpacity': 0.0,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
                 'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over'
        }); 
    } 

$var("a.group").attr('rel','gallery').fancybox({
'zoomSpeedIn':      500, 
                'zoomSpeedOut': 400, 
                'overlayShow':      false,
                'overlayOpacity': 0.0,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
                 'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over'
        }); 

            $var("a#inline").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': true,
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.6,
                                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
            });
});
</script>

<a id="fancybox" class="group" rel="group1"  title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat2.jpg">

<img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat2.jpg" alt="" /></a><i>Click on the photo above to view our gallery!</i>    <div class="hidden">

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat3.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat3.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat4.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat4.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat5.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat5.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat6.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat6.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat7.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat7.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat8.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat8.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat9.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat9.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<a id="fancybox" href="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat10.jpg"  class="group" rel="group1" title="Fly Fishing on the Delaware River"><img src="http://www.bigkevsguideservice.com/e107_themes/kubrick/images/boat10.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
```

Please note I have the extra thumbnails hiddens on this website but I've tried them hidden/not hidden and the titles still do not show.

Comment: Links to external sites are not good to have in a question without also including the relevant source code to your question. I suggest you also add the relevant source code to your question. Also have you checked the browser dev tools for errors or done any debugging?

Comment: Thanks I think I've edited and posted it with the code now. Hopefully someone can figure this one out!

Not sure on how to do dev tools or debugging either. I'm not a coder by any means. I just get by to get the few websites I want up.

Comment: Open your browser console, do you see any errors showing in the console? If so that will no doubt tell you the line number of where the error is and give some detail about the error. Also I see you are using the same `ID` over and over.... `ID`'s should be unique, if you want to target multiple elements i would recommend you use a `class` **Edit:** `Cmd` + `Option` + `J` to open google chromes console.

Comment: I don't know how to do this? I have  Mac OS X... use Safari & Google Chrome

Comment: Hitting cmd  option j shows pops up a console. But the list is blank.    As far as the id's for fancy box. The instructions for the plugin specifically say this: FancyBox options


To use the FancyBox-effect you need to add for image id="fancybox" attribute (wysiwyg editor switched off),

Example 1:




To use the FancyBox in separate photo gallery you need to add class="group" rel="group1" attribute for each image,